# Setting Line Styles For Gnuplot using multiplot

Tags: gnuplot

I prepared the following script to plot multiple plots. I predefined my line styles, as shown in the script. The line properties in the resulted figure
are not as they are defined in the script, plus I can not control the linewidths and the point sizes from the script. Any suggestions on what is causing the problem?

```
set terminal epslatex size 15cm, 15cm
set output "Figure1.tex"
set size 1.0,1.0
set origin 0.0,0.0
set xrange [0.1:0.8]
set xtics 0.1,0.2,0.9
set logscale y
set multiplot  layout 2,2
set linestyle 1 linecolor rgb 'red' pointtype 1   pointsize 2 linewidth 5 
set linestyle 2 linecolor rgb 'green' pointtype 2 pointsize 3 linewidth 5 
set linestyle 3 linecolor rgb 'blue' pointtype 3 pointsize 3 linewidth 5 
set linestyle 4 linecolor rgb 'yellow' pointtype 4 pointsize 3 linewidth 5
set linestyle 5 linecolor rgb 'magenta' pointtype 5 pointsize 3 linewidth 5  
set linestyle 6 linecolor rgb 'web-blue' pointtype 6 pointsize 3 linewidth 5  
set linestyle 7 linecolor rgb 'black' pointtype 7 pointsize 3 linewidth 5  
unset key
set yrange [2.8:6]
set ytics add ("3" 3.0, "6" 6.0 )
set lmargin 0
plot  " file1.txt" using 1:2   with linespoint  ls 1, "file2.txt" using 1:2   
with linespoint lt 2,\
"file3.txt" using 1:2   with linespoint lt 3,"file4.txt" using 1:2  with 
 linespoint lt 4,\
 "file5.txt" using 1:2   with linespoint lt 5,\
 "file6.txt" using 1:2  with linespoint lt 6,\
 "file7.txt" using 1:2   with linespoint lt 7
  unset lmargin
  set yrange[1.2:2.5]
  set ytics add ( "1.5" 1.5,"2.5" 2.5 )
  unset ylabel
  set rmargin 0
  plot  " file1.txt" using 1:3   with linespoint  ls 1, "file2.txt" using 1:3   
  with linespoint lt 2,\
 "file3.txt" using 1:3  with linespoint lt 3,"file4.txt" using 1:3  with 
  linespoint lt 4,\
 "file5.txt" using 1:3   with linespoint lt 5,\
 "file6.txt" using 1:3  with linespoint lt 6,\
 "file7.txt" using 1:23   with linespoint lt 7
  unset margin 
  set yrange[0.1:5.0]
 set ytics add ("" 1.0, "" 1.5, "" 2.5,"3" 3.0)
 set lmargin 0
 
 plot  " file1.txt" using 1:4   with linespoint  ls 1, "file2.txt" using 
 1:4   
 with linespoint lt 2,\
"file3.txt" using 1:3  with linespoint lt 3,"file4.txt" using 1:4  with 
linespoint 
lt 4,\
"file5.txt" using 1:4   with linespoint lt 5,\
"file6.txt" using 1:4  with linespoint lt 6,\
"file7.txt" using 1:4   with linespoint lt 7 
 unset lmargin
 set yrange[0.1:5.0]
 unset ylabel 
 set  key at 0.7,3.7 maxrows 4 Left reverse 
 set rmargin 0
 plot  "file1.txt" using 1:5 title '{Ou}'  with linespoint  ls 1, "file2.txt" using 1:5 title 
'{L}'  with linespoint lt 2,\
"file3.txt" using 1:5 title '{SL}'  with linespoint lt 3,"file4.txt" using 1:5 title '{CC}'  
 with linespoint lt 4,\
 "file5.txt" using 1:5 title '{HL}'  with linespoint lt 5,\
 "file6.txt" using 1:5 title '{HS}'  with linespoint lt 6,\
  "file7.txt" using 1:5 title '{SPi}'  with linespoint lt 7
  unset margin
  unset multiplot
  set output 
  set terminal pop
```

The figure I got is the following [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd9MA.jpg).

Comment: I cannot easily reproduce your graph because I don't have your data. Anyway, please mind the difference between `linestyle` (`ls`) and `linetype` (`lt`). You are defining linestyles (`ls`) but in your plot command you are using e.g. `lt 5` (linetype). I am also regularly confused by this difference ;-) Check `help linestyles vs linetypes `.

Comment: Actually in your plot commands you specify `ls 1`,  but `lt 2`, `lt 3`, ... `lt 7` ... a strange mix.

Comment: @theozh thanks so much for your comment, problem solved,  it was due to my mix between lt, and ls a  bad practice by me, but I am also confused about their difference. .

Comment: The difference is historical.  It used to be that linetypes were immutable.  In order to create customized combitions of color/width/etc you need a separate command "set style line".  Since version 5 you can customize the linetypes directly, so the "style" option is no longer needed but has been kept for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Ethan Thanks so much for your answer; it is clear to me now why they are coexisting. I want to mention that GPT3 produced the code for creating the line styles by a single line of inquiry.